# HTTP to HTTPS when there is a rooting system

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https

I would like to redirect every url of my website from http:// to https://

My problem is that I alerady have a routing system in my .htaccess :

```
RewriteRule ([^.]+)\.html$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

I tried to add this, but the route is broken :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off    
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks !

Comment: How is the route broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the good statements :

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add HTTP to HTTPS before old RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off    
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

RewriteRule ([^.]+)\.html$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works on my development environment (MAMP) but on my testing environments (server) it causes a redirection loop !

Comment: Not a problem with the https certificate or server configuration ?

Comment: I asked the admin, but unfortunately he is unavailable until next week.
I'll come back when I know more.